# How to remotely degug msgina.dll?

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, remote-debugging, gina

I have a fully customized msgina.dll in module i need to remotely debug it? Ho will i achieve this

Abdul Khaliq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been some time since I last dug into GINA development.

What I did: was create a virtual machine with a version of windows for debugging (you'll also need the symbols I think)

You can map the serial port of the virtual pc and let WinDbg (debug tool that came with the windows SDK) connect to it.

I was able to succesfully debug and receive message from the moment windows started up. (and I used windows XP for development and the target OS, without any isseus)

This technique works even without the initialization of your GINA working, which is necessary in the technique explained in: http://pluralsight.com/wiki/default.aspx/Keith/GinaDebugging.html

A quick google turned up following detailed description to setup what I explained:
Using VMWARE:
http://www.etdot.com/2008/04/16/windbg-and-vmware/

Answer (score 1):

For remote GINA debugging you can use the instructions on the following site:

http://pluralsight.com/wiki/default.aspx/Keith/GinaDebugging.html

The site was down when I visited it so take a look at the  [Google Cache](http://74.125.155.132/search?q=cache:Oy72oFRu84AJ:alt.pluralsight.com/wiki/default.aspx/Keith/GinaDebugging.html+pluralsight.com/wiki/default.aspx/Keith/GinaDebugging.html&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us) version

You can also do it using a single computer using the instructions at the link below.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260901